# Definition of a smooth function on $[0,1]^k$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $f: [0,1]^k \rightarrow M$ be a continuous function which is smooth on $(0,1)^k$.  I have seen two definitions of what it means for $f$ to be smooth.  First, there exists an open neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb R^k$ such that $f$ extends to a smooth function on $U$.  Second, at each point $p$ on the boundary of $[0,1]^k$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $f$ extends to a smooth function on $U \cap (0,1)^k$.

Are these two definitions equivalent?  If not, what should be the "correct" definition?  Say, for the purpose of defining singular homology and integration of differential forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these definitions are equivalents. The first one clearly implies the second. Using the notion of partition of unity (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity)), you can show that the second one also implies the first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both definition are equivalent. You can use partitions of unity: Suppose that for every $x$ in $[0,1]^k$ there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ and a smooth function $f_x:U\cap (0,1)^k \to M$ wich agrees with $f$. By compactness of $[0,1]^k$ there exists a finite cover $\{U_1,\ldots, U_r\}$  of $[0,1]^k$ consisting in some of such neighborhoods. Take a partition of unity $\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_r\}$ subordinated to the cover and define $F:\cup_iU_i\to M$ by the formula $F(x)=\sum_i\varphi_i(x)f_i(x)$.